# Dozer mapping two classes with mismatched argument counts

Tags: java, dozer, object-object-mapping

I have two beans, one has five attributes and the other has four.  How do I configure the mapping if I simply want to ignore the extra attribute?

All of the exclude examples I see take an argument for both class one and class two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do anything; Dozer should handle this out the box.

Consider the following two beans:

**Source.java**

```
public class Source {

    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    private String field3;

   // Getters and setters omitted

}
```

**Destination.java**

```
public class Destination {

    private String field1;
    private String field2;

    // Getters and setters omitted

}
```

You can use the following mapping in your dozer.xml file (this will map all properties where the names match in both beans):

```
<mapping>
    <class-a>com.example.Source</class-a>
    <class-b>com.example.Destination</class-b>
</mapping>
```

The following unit tests show that the mapping works both ways:

```
    @Test
    public void sourceToDestination() {
        List<String> mappingFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
        mappingFiles.add("dozer.xml");
        this.beanMapper = new DozerBeanMapper(mappingFiles);

        Source source = new Source();
        source.setField1("A");
        source.setField2("B");
        source.setField3("C");

        Destination dest = beanMapper.map(source, Destination.class);
        assertEquals("A", dest.getField1());
        assertEquals("B", dest.getField2());
    }

    @Test
    public void destinationToSource() {
        List<String> mappingFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
        mappingFiles.add("dozer.xml");
        this.beanMapper = new DozerBeanMapper(mappingFiles);

        Destination dest = new Destination();
        dest.setField1("A");
        dest.setField2("B");

        Source source = beanMapper.map(dest, Source.class);
        assertEquals("A", source.getField1());
        assertEquals("B", source.getField2());
        assertNull(source.getField3());
    }
```

When we map Source to Destination, as Destination does not have a property named `field3` it is ignored. When we map the other way (Destination to Source), `field3` in Source is null.